# Which camera to use to film without moire effect

Tags: moire

I am trying to make a video of a simple cushion which is on a rotating disk. But I am getting so much moire that the video is unusable. At this moment I am using a Canon 5d Mark2 with a zoom lens 24-70mm. See the link below for a picture of the video.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbgWB.jpg

I am ready to buy some new equipment to get rid of this moire effect (around € 1000,-). But I have no idea what to buy. As far as I can find it is not a simple problem which can be fixed with a simple filter. However I found the filter in the link below. I emailed the company to ask if this filter will fix my problem but didn’t get an answer.

http://www.mosaicengineering.com/products/vaf/5d2.html

At this moment I have no idea what to do, buy a new camera? And which one? Or buy that filter?

I am leaning to a new camera because I can test it before I buy it, the filter have to be ordered in the US and send to the Netherlands which makes it really difficult to return, if it is not working.

Can someone please give me some advice how to tackle this moire problem. I will be really happy to read your advice's